# Consumir Service WCF en asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

Buenas Dias :

Por favor que me puedan ayudar estoy tratando de consumir un servicio en WCF en lenguaje programacion asp.net c#  pero cuando trata de consumir me sale un error que time out he intentado poner en el webconfig timeout pero igual me sale ese error.

alguien me pudiera ayudar por favor el codigo es el siguiente:

```
 SvcCreditoExterno.SvcCreditoExternoClient sv = new SvcCreditoExterno.SvcCreditoExternoClient();

            SvcCreditoExterno.DtoGeneradorTablaAmortizacionRequest svs = new SvcCreditoExterno.DtoGeneradorTablaAmortizacionRequest();

            SvcCreditoExterno.DtoRubroDiferidoRequest dtorubro = new SvcCreditoExterno.DtoRubroDiferidoRequest();

           // svs.AjustarTabla = SvcCreditoExterno.EnumeradosConfiguracionNegocioMetodosAjusteTabla.AjustePrimeraCuota;

            //svs.TipoGracia = SvcCreditoExterno.EnumeradosConfiguracionNegocioTipoGracia.GraciaCapital;
            //svs.TipoTabla = SvcCreditoExterno.EnumeradosConfiguracionNegocioTipoTabla.CapitalFijo.ToString();
           // svs.FactorDeRedondeo = SvcCreditoExterno.EnumeradosConfiguracionNegocioFactorRedondeo.Centécimas;

            svs.AjustarTabla = SvcCreditoExterno.EnumeradosConfiguracionNegocioMetodosAjusteTabla.SinAjuste;

            bool aplicaalgoritmoredondedocuota = Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32(1));
            svs.AplicaAlgoritmoRedondeoCuota = aplicaalgoritmoredondedocuota;

            bool AplicaDiaLaborable = Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32(1));
            svs.AplicaDiaLaborable= AplicaDiaLaborable;

            bool AplicaDiaLaborableFinSemanaAdelante = Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32(1));
            svs.AplicaDiaLaborableFinSemanaAdelante= AplicaDiaLaborableFinSemanaAdelante;

            bool AplicaFechasIguales = Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32(1));
            svs.AplicaFechasIguales= AplicaFechasIguales;

            bool AplicaFindeMes = Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32(1));
            svs.AplicaFindeMes= AplicaFindeMes;

            bool AplicaPrimerVencimiento = Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32(1));
            svs.AplicaPrimerVencimiento=AplicaPrimerVencimiento;

            int BaseCalculo=360/350;
            svs.BaseCalculo=BaseCalculo;

            int plazo = 12;
            svs.Plazo = plazo;

            bool GeneraTasaObjetivo = Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32(2));
            svs.GeneraTasaObjetivo = GeneraTasaObjetivo;

            decimal Tasa = Convert.ToDecimal(12.5);
            svs.Tasa = Tasa;

            decimal monto = Convert.ToDecimal(200.00);
            svs.Monto = monto;

            int Periodicidad = 12;
            svs.Periodicidad = Periodicidad;

            svs.TipoGracia = SvcCreditoExterno.EnumeradosConfiguracionNegocioTipoGracia.GraciaCapital;

            int PeriodosGracia = 1;
            svs.PeriodosGracia = PeriodosGracia;

            int Decimales = 2;
            svs.Decimales = Decimales;

            int DecimalesCuota = 2;
            svs.DecimalesCuota = DecimalesCuota;

            int DecimalesTasa = 2;
            svs.DecimalesTasa = DecimalesTasa;



            DateTime Fecha1erVencimiento = Convert.ToDateTime("2017-06-26");
            svs.Fecha1erVencimiento=Fecha1erVencimiento;

            int Institucion = 1;
            svs.Institucion = Institucion;

            int Oficina = 1;
            svs.Oficina = Oficina;



             int NumeroCuotas = Convert.ToInt32(txtNumeroCuota.Text);
             svs.NumeroCuotas = NumeroCuotas;

             DateTime FechaInicioTabla = Convert.ToDateTime(txtFechaDesembolso.Text);
             svs.FechaInicioTabla = FechaInicioTabla;

             int PeriodicidadCapital = 12;
             svs.PeriodicidadCapital = PeriodicidadCapital;

             decimal MontoTIR2 = 200;
             svs.MontoTIR2 = MontoTIR2;

             decimal MontoTIR3 = 0;
             svs.MontoTIR3 = MontoTIR3;

             bool AplicaAlgoritmoRedondeoCuota = Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32(1));
             svs.AplicaAlgoritmoRedondeoCuota = AplicaAlgoritmoRedondeoCuota;

             svs.RedondeoHacia = SvcCreditoExterno.EnumeradosConfiguracionNegocioTipoRedondeo.Arriba;

             svs.FactorDeRedondeo = SvcCreditoExterno.EnumeradosConfiguracionNegocioFactorRedondeo.Centécimas;

             decimal TasaInicialObjetivo = Convert.ToDecimal(12.5);
             svs.TasaInicialObjetivo = TasaInicialObjetivo;

             decimal MontoCapitalFijo = Convert.ToDecimal(250.0);
             svs.MontoCapitalFijo = MontoCapitalFijo;

             int idproducto = 1;
             svs.Idproducto = idproducto;

             int CodigoSectorOrganismoControl = Convert.ToInt32(1);
             svs.CodigoSectorOrganismoControl = CodigoSectorOrganismoControl;

             decimal Gradiente = Convert.ToDecimal(12.4);
             svs.Gradiente = Gradiente;

             decimal PorcentajeMinimoCuoton = Convert.ToDecimal(12);
             svs.PorcentajeMinimoCuoton = PorcentajeMinimoCuoton;

             sv.ConsultarTablaAmortizacion(svs);
```

Este es el mensaje de error :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Eso se debe a los tiepos de espera definidos en el tipo de Binding que usa el cliente para conectarse al servicio:

Poniendo un ejemplo, verifica en el **web.config del cliente**, en este caso tu aplicación Web y asegurate que los tiempos de espera sean los suficientes para recibir la respuesta. En el siguiente ejemplo asume que se esta usando el tipo de binding **basicHttpBinding**:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpsBinding_ILDAPHelper" maxReceivedMessageSize="20971520" receiveTimeout="00:02:10" sendTimeout="00:02:10">
```

Suerte!